# Stopping time + constant

Tags: measure-theory, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Then we know that $\{ \tau \leq t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t\geq 0$.

But how do I prove that $\tau+s$ for $s \geq 0$ is a stopping time aswell?

Comment: $\{\tau+s\leq t\}=\{\tau\leq t-s\}\in \mathcal F_{t-s}\subset \mathcal F_t.$

Comment: But what if $t < s$? Is $\mathcal{F}_{t-s}$ defined then?

Comment: if $t<s$ then $\{\tau<t-s\}=\varnothing \in \mathcal F_t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $t \ge s$.

$$ \{ \tau + s   \le t \}  =  \{ \tau  \le t -s \} \in \mathcal{F}_{t-s}$$
because $\tau$ is stopping time.

Thus
$$ \{ \tau + s   \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_{t-s} \subset  \mathcal{F}_{t}$$
by definition of filtration.

Hence, $$ \{ \tau + s   \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$$
and $\tau + s$ is stopping time.

Now suppose that  $t < s$. Thus $\{ \tau + s   \le t \} = \{ \tau  \le t -s \} = \varnothing \in  \mathcal{F}_{t}.$

Is there any questions?

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are welcome!